# Why does my python script download instead of run?

Tags: python, django, fastcgi

I am attempting to deploy my Django project on my shared web host using an .htaccess rewrite and a python script that runs FastCGI. I am using this method because I do not have the ability to change and Apache configuration. When I visit the site, instead of running the FastCGI script it downloads or displays the contents of the script file. I have made the script executable using chmod +x mysite.fcgi. I have placed the script in cgi-bin, but nothing works. The script will run from the command line.

### .htaccess

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cgi-bin/mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

### mysite.fcgi

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os

# Add a custom Python path.
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/jmjordan/.local/lib/python")
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/jmjordan/.local/lib/python/flup")


# Switch to the directory of your project. (Optional.)
# os.chdir("/home/user/myproject")

# Set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "jmjordan.settings"

from django.core.servers.fastcgi import runfastcgi
runfastcgi(method="threaded", daemonize="false")
```

Comment: Many hosting companies are *not* Django/Python friendly (or even FastCGI friendly). I don't know where you are hosting, but WebFaction is about as Django & FastCGI friendly a place as you'll find. I'm not associated, just a happy customer.

Comment: My host says they support Python and FastCGI, but they are more focused on ease of use instead of more advanced web development. It might be time for a change. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
<Files mysite.fcgi>
    SetHandler fastcgi-script
</Files>
```

somewhere in your Apache configuration. `AddHandler` just puts a handler in Apache's list of available handlers; you have to use `SetHandler` to use it.

This is probably a security measure to prevent someone from uploading a file with a `.fcgi` suffix and running arbitrary code on your server.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is on a shared host and I do not have access the the Apache configuration.

Comment: I added that to .htaccess and the script still does not run.

Comment: I don't believe that `<Files>` is allowed outside of the Apache conf file.